# How would you get a count of values in one Column based on the range of values in another in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So I want to count the number of occurrences for a value (lets say TCP) in a column based on a timeframe in another column.

I have network data which I have loaded into pandas which looks like this:

| No. | Time | Protocol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | ARP |
| 2 | 0.0009 | ARP |
| 3 | 1.852702 | UDP |
| 4 | 1.852818 | TLSv1.2 |
| 5 | 1.954154 | TLSv1.2 |
| 6 | 1.966039 | UDP |
| 7 | 2.004607 | TCP |
| 8 | 2.566356 | TLSv1.2 |
| 9 | 2.61589 | TCP |
| 10 | 2.674273 | TLSv1.2 |
| 11 | 2.752145 | TCP |
| 12 | 4.907819 | TCP |
| 13 | 5.588816 | UDP |
| 14 | 5.836231 | TCP |
| 15 | 5.848303 | DNS |
| 16 | 5.861939 | TCP |
| 17 | 5.881559 | DNS |
| 18 | 5.884081 | TCP |
| 19 | 5.908872 | TCP |
| 20 | 5.909202 | TCP |

What I would like to do is count the number of instances of TCP in the protocol column in the range of 0 to 2.7 in the Time column. Then hopefully use the same method for counting the number of instances from 2.7 to 5.91.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) for selection of `Time` range `[0..2.7]`.  Then, use [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get the value count of `'TCP'`, as follows:

```
df.loc[df['Time'].between(0, 2.7) & (df['Protocol'] == 'TCP'), 'Protocol'].value_counts()
```

**Result:**

```
TCP    2
Name: Protocol, dtype: int64
```

Similarly, for counting within `Time` range `[2.7..5.91]`, you can use:

```
df.loc[df['Time'].between(2.7, 5.91) & (df['Protocol'] == 'TCP'), 'Protocol'].value_counts()
```

**Result:**

```
TCP    7
Name: Protocol, dtype: int64
```

For more precise selection of values, you can also use the `inclusive=` parameter of [`.between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html).  For example, if for the second range, 2.7 is not included (i.e.  `2.7 < x <= 5.91` instead of `2.7 <= x <= 5.91`, you can use:

```
df.loc[df['Time'].between(2.7, 5.91, inclusive='right') & (df['Protocol'] == 'TCP'), 'Protocol'].value_counts()
```

If there is no match, the result will show as an empty Series, as follows. For example:

```
df.loc[df['Time'].between(0, 2.0) & (df['Protocol'] == 'TCP'), 'Protocol'].value_counts()
```

**Result:**

```
Series([], Name: Protocol, dtype: int64)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the info.  I am trying this answer first and it works as suggested.  I was messing about with the start and end times though and it crashes if there is no 'TCP' value found.  Just wondering if you knew a way round this.  For example if you change the 2.7 to 2.0 in the first example:

Comment: @ColinCrook  Ok, let me look at it.

Comment: @ColinCrook  Actually, you can use the code without the last `['TCP']` part to look at the whole list of value_counts within the range.  If you don't see `TCP` in the list of counts, it will be zero.

Comment: @ColinCrook  See my edit above.   Amended to select `TCP` within `loc` so that you won't get a crash when there is no match.  It will show as an empty series for no match.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this approach.

***import necessary packages***

```
import pandas as pd
```

***Test data***

```
    Time    Protocol
0   0.000000    ARP
1   0.009000    ARP
2   1.852702    UDP
3   1.852818    TLSv1.2
4   1.954154    TLSv1.2
5   1.966039    UDP
6   2.004607    TCP
7   2.566356    TLSv1.2
8   2.615890    TCP
9   2.674273    TLSv1.2
10  2.752145    TCP
11  4.907819    TCP
12  5.588816    UDP
13  5.836231    TCP
14  5.848303    DNS
15  5.861939    TCP
16  5.881559    DNS
17  5.884081    TCP
18  5.908872    TCP
19  5.909202    TCP
```

***Define the extract function***

```
def extract_info(df, time_start, time_end, protocal_name):
    df = df.loc[(df['Protocol'] == protocal_name) & (df['Time'] >= time_start) & (df['Time'] <= time_end)]
    
    return df
```

***Test case 1 [time range is (0, 2.7), protocol : 'TCP']***

```
df_TCP = extract_info(df, 0.0, 2.7, 'TCP')
print('Count : ', len(df_TCP.index))
df_TCP
```

result

```
Count :  2
    Time    Protocol
6   2.004607    TCP
8   2.615890    TCP
```

***Test case 2 [time range is (2.7, 5.91), protocol : 'TCP']***

```
df_TCP = extract_info(df, 2.7, 5.91, 'TCP')
print('Count : ', len(df_TCP.index))
df_TCP
```

result

```
Count :  7
    Time    Protocol
10  2.752145    TCP
11  4.907819    TCP
13  5.836231    TCP
15  5.861939    TCP
17  5.884081    TCP
18  5.908872    TCP
19  5.909202    TCP
```

Hope this one would be helpful to you. Best.

Comment: What if there is a `Time` entry of exactly `2.7` ?   Will it be counted twice (duplicated) for the 2 calls ?

Comment: If so, what you want exactly?